# Issue in splitting an array of strings

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm using webrequests to retrieve data in a .txt file that's on my dropbox using this "format".

```
SomeStuff
AnotherStuff
StillAnother
```

And i'm using this code to retrieve each line and read it:

```
Private Sub DataCheck()
    Dim datarequest As HttpWebRequest = CType(HttpWebRequest.Create("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com.txt"), HttpWebRequest)
    Dim dataresponse As HttpWebResponse = CType(datarequest.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
    Dim sr2 As System.IO.StreamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(dataresponse.GetResponseStream())
    Dim datastring() As String = sr2.ReadToEnd().Split(CChar(Environment.NewLine))
    If datastring(datastring.Length - 1) <> String.Empty Then

        For Each individualdata In datastring
            MessageBox.Show(individualdata)
            Console.WriteLine(individualdata)
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

The problem is, the output is this:

[image]

It always adds a line break (equal to " " as i see as first character on each but the first line string) after the first line like:
http://img203.imageshack.us/img203/1296/gejb.png

Why this happens? I tried also replacing the Environment.Newline with nothing like this:

```
Dim newstring as String = individualdata.Replace(Environment.Newline, String.Empty)
```

But the result was the same... what's the problem here? I tried with multiple newline strings and consts like vbnewline, all had the same result, any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not splitting by `NewLine` since you are cutting off `Environment.NewLine` which is a `string` with `CChar`. You just have to use the overload of `String.Split` that takes a `String()` and a `StringSplitOption`:

So instead of

```
Dim text = sr2.ReadToEnd()
Dim datastring() As String = text.Split(CChar(Environment.NewLine))
```

this

```
Dim datastring() As String = text.Split({Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.None)
```

Comment: Thanks, that works !! I may have to study more about splitting since i never used the overloads... I was converting with CChar because i didn't remember to use curly brackets in this case and Option Strict complained :p

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that your file contains a mix of NewLine+CarriageReturn (vbCrLf) and a simple NewLine (vbLf).
If this is the case then you could create an array of the possible separators

```
Dim seps(2) as Char 
seps(0) = CChar(vbLf)
seps(1) = CChar(vbCr)
Dim datastring() As String = sr2.ReadToEnd().Split(seps, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

The StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries is required because a vbCrLf creates an empty string between the two separators

Comment: Your solution also works, thank you very much, i didn't knew that ;)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, searched everywhere this is the only working.